# Any reason to use restoreCompletedTransactions given appStoreReceiptURL in iOS7/8?

Tags: ios, ios7, in-app-purchase

I am in the process of updating my app to new iOS7/8 in-app purchase libraries. I see now that as of iOS7, we have access to [`appStoreReceiptURL`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSBundle/appStoreReceiptURL) as part of NSBundle.

It appears I can access this URL, and its concomitant data, at any time, without interacting or interfacing with the [`SKPaymentQueue`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentQueue_Class/index.html).

Previously, when a customer installed our app and wanted to restore his in-app subscription, the app would call the [`restoreCompletedTransactions`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentQueue_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKPaymentQueue/restoreCompletedTransactions) method of `[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]`, and from that obtain receipt information, one transaction at a time, that the app would upload to our server one transaction at a time.

However, while testing in the iOS App Store Sandbox, now I appear to be able to obtain one piece of master receipt data from `[[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL]`, upload that to my server, obtain a complete history of every in-app transaction this user has made, and then record transactions on my server as appropriate and send notification back to my client.

Consequently, why or when would anyone need to call `restoreCompletedTransactions`? In my app, I sell a single, auto-renewing in-app subscription; are there other use cases today in iOS7/8 for which this API is still helpful?

Answer (score 2):

If a user has made a purchase on a different device, it can be useful (or necessary) to "restore" that purchase on a new device. restoreCompletedTransactions could enable this restore operation. By default, on this new device, I believe the >= iOS7 style receipt will not have those prior purchases. On >= iOS7, SKReceiptRefreshRequest will work in many cases.

From Apple:

> In most cases, all your app needs to do is refresh its receipt and
> deliver the products in its receipt. The refreshed receipt contains a
> record of the user’s purchases in this app, on this device or any
> other device. However, some apps need to take an alternate approach
> for one of the following reasons:
>
> If you use Apple-hosted content, restoring completed transactions
> gives your app the transaction objects it uses to download the
> content.
>
> If you need to support versions of iOS earlier than iOS 7,
> where the app receipt isn’t available, restore completed transactions
> instead.
>
> If your app uses non-renewing subscriptions, your app is
> responsible for the restoration process.

See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Restoring.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH8-SW9